# Regex - everything after the last occurrence

Tags: regex, python-re

I have this text:
**ABC anything about the sky ABC and anything about the moon**

I'm trying to write a REGEX to get everything after the last occurrence of 'ABC':

Example:

**ABC anything about the sky ABC and anything about the moon**
*and anything about the moon*

**ABC anything about the sky ABC and anything ABC about the moon**
*about the moon*

I was trying the expression below, but it considers ABC as separatelly letters, so it would match wrong if there was a single 'A' after 'ABC' in the text:

```
[^ABC]*$
```

PS: I'm trying an expression which does not make groups and i'm using python3

Comment: Match using `.*\bABC\b(.*)` and grab 1st captured group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a group, you could make use of lookarounds:

```
(?<=\bABC\s)(?!.*\bABC\b).*
```

- `(?<=\bABC\s)` Positive lookbehind, assert ABC and a whitespace char to the left
- `(?!.*\bABC\b)` Negative lookahead, assert no occurrence of ABC to the right
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times (or `.+` if there should at least be a single character)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ItZRw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9O5CTW)

---

If you want to support quantifier in the lookbehind assertion, you could use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). For example

```
(?<=\bABC \d+ )(?!.*\bABC\b).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xIiIQJ/1/) | [Pyhon demo](https://tio.run/##pZCxDoIwFEVn@xXPTi0aEmGVEPU3upRQgQivpH0m8vW1NC4kJg6ON@feM9x5od5iGcIwzdYRONOZF2OzJjIOoQLHRX2uVHO53kC1B5Ci3udZyqqRecYZ87Em@FrQGHUDdqAb@ySg3oB/LLCiU1FG3H6rTNaiQs52vxybfZL@bdnuEy@AjCcu4wtuQBLpkvw@YKvHUXyeOYKXMoQ3)

Comment: I also tried this one, but using (?<= ... i can't put quantifiers, for example if ABC is followed by numbers i could not get it working by using (?<=\bABC \d+ ...

Comment: @GustavoBordin that is because python does not support quantifiers in a lookbehind. You can use the PyPi regex module if you want that. Like https://regex101.com/r/xIiIQJ/1